# x86 MUL operation at hardware level

Tags: x86, cpu-architecture, intel

I understand the the x86 operation to perform integer multiplication of two numbers (e.g. on 64 bits) is `MUL`.

My question is, how is this operation generally implemented at the hardware level? (for instance, on a modern Intel processor). Also, is it executed in a single CPU cycle?

Comment: Hello! This doesn't appear to be a programming / software development question. Questions about the electrical design / implementation of CPUs will likely be closed as off-topic on this site, but may be suitable for https://electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: The latency (of the `rax` result) is generally 3 cycles on high performance x86 cores or 5 on the low power x86 cores (Intel Atom and the E-cores in hybrid architectures), source: https://uops.info/table.html So not single-cycle, but fast enough that it has to involve a proper high-performance multiplier, not just a shift-and-add loop.

Comment: Normally you'd use `imul reg,reg`, unless you actually need the high half of the result.  It's single-uop with 3 cycle latency on modern Intel and AMD.  (Or more on E cores).  But it is fully pipelined, able to start an independent multiply every clock cycle, on Intel for a while and AMD since Zen 1.  (Bulldozer's multipliers weren't fully pipelined, with 64-bit operand-size being extra slow.)  See https://uops.info/ and https://agner.org/optimize/

Comment: @Brian hello, instruction latencies and the other scheduling details are absolutely programming-related questions. Still, there are so many x86 cores out there that the question cannot have a meaningful answer.

Comment: And, just for comparison, a single-cycle 32-bit integer multiplication is indeed possible and many ARM cores implement it, using a Dadda multiplier with large lookup tables.